# When does bimolecular nucleophilic substitution reaction take place in phenyl group containing compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

We were studying S<sub>N</sub> Mechanism, and our professor gave us a question to identify the S<sub>N</sub>, mechanisms which would happen in the given compound.

They were $\ce{CH3Cl}$, $\ce{PhCH2Cl}$, $\ce{Ph2CHCl}$, $\ce{Ph3CCl}$.

So while attempting the given problem, I chose S<sub>N</sub>1 for both $\ce{Ph2CHCl}$ & $\ce{Ph3CCl}$,as they would face a lot of hindrance. But our professor told us that they both can also perform S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism. Why would they both perform S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism despite there being a lot of hindrance present?

My Reasoning: Although $\ce{PhCH2+}$ would be resonance stabilized but the hindrance present is too much for S<sub>N</sub>2 to proceed.

Comment: Your own reasoning, based on search and analysis, is supposed to be present to avoid the question closure for lack of own effort.

Comment: Honestly, it’s completely ridiculous to suggest that trityl chloride could undergo SN2, and also very disappointing to see such things being taught as if they were true. I’d wager that diphenylmethyl chloride also almost certainly favours SN1. With secondary halides it tends to be more nuanced, but here the groups are pretty bulky and the SN1 carbocation intermediate is pretty stable.

Comment: That line of logic is pretty useless. These molecules may also fall apart randomly into three phenyl radicals, a chlorine atom, and a carbon atom. The chances of that happening are basically zero as well. One could insist that that’s *possible*, which may well be true, but you wouldn’t learn anything useful from that assertion. Insisting that trityl chloride can undergo SN2 is technically correct, but pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any reaction capable of undergoing in two or more mechanisms has major and minor pathways. In your question the major pathway is obviously S<sub>N</sub>1 due to high steric hindrance and the resonance-stabilized carbocation, and the minor pathway is S<sub>N</sub>2. Since, your professor said they can ALSO perform S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism, I think he was trying to say that the reaction doesn't only react via the S<sub>N</sub>1 pathway, but also via the minor S<sub>N</sub>2 pathway. However, the major pathway is definitely S<sub>N</sub>1 due to high steric hindrance and resonance stabilized carbocation.